# array_replace alternatives for earlier version of php?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking to use the array_replace function but the version of php I'm running doesn't support it. I was wondering if anyone new of any alternative ways of doing this?

The version of php I'm running is 5.2.17

I have an array and I just want to replace elements with another array where the keys match.

I'm not able to update the version of php on the server btw :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
$array;
$replacement;
foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
  if (array_key_exists($key, $replacement)) {
    $value = $replacement[$key];
  }
}
```

or just

```
foreach ($replacement as $key => $value) {
  $array[$key] = $value;
}
```

or maybe even

```
array_merge ($array, $replacement);
```

(I currently don't see any difference in the behaviour of `array_merge()` and `array_replace()` ...)

Comment: there is a big difference between the two function with how they deal with array of numeric keys, array_merge will re-assign numeric keys while array_replace will not. array_merge will not over-write your value for a numeric keys while array_replace will.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a real backport of this function you can use this code:
http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-replace.php#92549

```
if (!function_exists('array_replace'))
{
  function array_replace( array &$array, array &$array1 )
  {
    $args = func_get_args();
    $count = func_num_args();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
      if (is_array($args[$i])) {
        foreach ($args[$i] as $key => $val) {
          $array[$key] = $val;
        }
      }
      else {
        trigger_error(
          __FUNCTION__ . '(): Argument #' . ($i+1) . ' is not an array',
          E_USER_WARNING
        );
        return NULL;
      }
    }

    return $array;
  }
}
```

Thanks to dyer85(at)gmail(dot)com

Comment: Arrays should not be passed as reference in array_replace()

Comment: @JoryHogeveen Oh, I sincerely hope you're not running a version of PHP older than 5.3.0 ...

Comment: Haha no worries. Just making my WP plugin tests compatible with 5.2 (TravisCI) since that is what WP is still supporting unfortunately.